# How do I set up a route to a custom method in a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I created (read generated) a scaffold. In the same generated controller, I defined a custom method which just executes a `puts` command in the console. How can I call this method? Where do I set up the routes for the method in question? I'm trying to call the method with an ajax call, but I keep getting Resource not found (404).

routes:

```
 resources :projects do
    collection do
      put 'export_excel'
    end
  end
```

controller:

```
def export_excel
    puts 'yay from controller'
end
```

front-end:

```
exportExcel: function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/projects/export_excel",
                async: false,
                success: function(){
                    console.log('yay!');
                },
                error: function(){
                    console.log('nay!');
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Type POST != Type PUT.  change route to be post 'export_excel' as opposed to put (but in reality as it isn't changing a resource, or the like but asking for something, it should probably be a `get`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your custom  method operate on all records AKA `collection` or a single record  aka `member`

in routes you can add custom methods by providing a block to your `resources` definition

```
 resources :models  do 
     collection  do  
        get 'custom_method' 
     end
  end 


 resources :models  do 
     member  do  
        post 'custom_method' 
     end
  end
```

see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions  for more info

based on comments / updated

```
resources :projects do 
  collection do 
     get 'export_excel', as: :export
  end
end
```

```
exportExcel: function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/projects/export_excel",
                async: false,
                success: function(){
                    console.log('yay!');
                },
                error: function(){
                    console.log('nay!');
                }
            });
        }
```

As the http verbs need to match,  (in your ajax had POST, route had PUT).  I think it should probably be a `GET` in both. But regardless they need to match

also you can't use `puts` from inside the controller,  you either need to use the Rails Logger, or render something back to the browser  such as

```
def export_excel
    render text: 'yay from controller'
end
```

Comment: okay so the controller name is Projects. There I want to define an action called exportExcel so. Basically i'm trying to call the following url: localhost:3000/projects/exportExcel I don't need ids in my url at all.

Comment: yes I do, however I still keep getting "NetworkError: 404 Not Found  - localhost:3000/projects/export_excel"

Comment: Doon, not too sure what you meant by rake routes. I know what rake is in the ruby ecosystem but that's about it.. never used one really, only once for migration of the db schema

Comment: if you type `rake routes` much like `rake db:migrate` , rails will drop how it parsed your routes to the console. so you can see  how urls are laid out etc...

Comment: export_excel_projects PUT    /projects/export_excel(.:format)      projects#export_excel <- here is the relevant line from the output. I still keep getting the same error as above..

Comment: UPDATE: When i change the HTTP Reqst to PUT I get 500 internal server error. How can I change the request type to GET?

Comment: you are getting the 500, since you are trying to use puts in your method.  Either use  the rails `logger` to log the log, render a template or do something like render text: 'Yay' to send it back to the browser

Comment: Yes I too would avoid the ajax here. and just make the GET request directly. – Doon 1 min ago <-> Ok so can you provide me with the button helper in rails which would call the above mentioned method?

Answer (score 1):

in config/routes.rb add a route for your new controller method.

example: in config/routes.rb

```
resources :users do 
    collection do
       put 'new_method_name'
   end 
end
```

Comment: do u need to export any data? u cant do that with an ajax request. also verbs need to match. 'put' need if that is in your route

Comment: I just wanna call a function which then, using a ruby library, will generate an excel and will return it back to the user.

Comment: how do you plan to do that? u need to use 'send_data' to export excel file. but u can't do this with ajax request.

Comment: Yes I too would avoid the ajax here.  and just make the GET request directly.

Comment: ok so can you provide me with the necessary rails button helper which would call the above mentioned function??

Comment: also y do need ajax. 'send_data' doesn't render anything. use 'http' request.

Comment: type 'rake routes' in terminal. then use the route and append '_path' in link_to and use 'get' request. example: link_to 'Export', export_excel_projects_path'

Comment: I did already. This is the relevant line export_excel_projects GET /projects/export_excel(.:format) projects#export_excel